# Deserialize Json from file in C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

### I've managed to find a solution without removing the paths from the keys.
Thanks for the help guys, and also pointing out problems, I really appreciate it! :)

Loaded the Json to a string, deserialized it into a dynamic, ran a foreach through it, and added to a List with ResFiles in it.

```
static void loadJson()
{
    List<ResFile> fileList = new List<ResFile>();
    string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(jsonPath);
    dynamic files = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

    foreach (var f in files.objects)
        fileList.Add(new ResFile(f.Name, f.Value.hash.ToString(), (int)f.Value.size.Value));
}
```

---

**I'm trying to deserialize some Json file in C# with Newtonsoft's Json library.**
The files are named after it's hash, not the real file name and I want to rename them back to the proper names, so like this:
*10a54fc66c8f479bb65c8d39c3b62265ac82e742* >> *file_1.ext*

The Json file:

```
{
  "files": {
    "file_1.ext": {
      "hash": "10a54fc66c8f479bb65c8d39c3b62265ac82e742",
      "size": 8112
    },
    "file_2.ext": {
      "hash": "14cfb2f24e7d91dbc22a2a0e3b880d9829320243",
      "size": 7347
    },
    "file_3.ext": {
      "hash": "bf7fadaf64945f6b31c803d086ac6a652aabef9b",
      "size": 3838
    },
    "file_4.ext": {
      "hash": "48f7e1bb098abd36b9760cca27b9d4391a23de26",
      "size": 6905
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried deserialize with this:

```
static void loadJson()
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(jsonPath))
    {
        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        dynamic files = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    }
}
```

The deserialization itself working, but I don't know how to loop through them.

I've also tried to do this:

```
class ResFile
{
    public string name;
    public string hash;
    public int size;
}
```

And somehow force the deserialization to use this, but it didn't work of course.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to your sample json, your classes would be:

```
public class ResFile
{
    public string hash { set; get; }
    public int size { set; get; }
}

public class ResRoot
{
    public Dictionary<string, ResFile> Files { set; get; }
}
```

---

You can deserialize as

```
var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResRoot>(File.ReadAllText(filename));
```

---

```
foreach(var f in res.Files)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name={0} Size={1}", f.Key, f.Value.size);
}
```

Comment: It gives NullRef error, the res object is empty. The path is correct however, and the file read in correctly. Something in the deserialization not working.

Comment: @DavidDosa Given your json sample, above code works. Tested it before posting.

Comment: The file, with real data in it contains 3k lines, with almost 100k characters...Maybe this is the problem, because I've got your code working, and really, with the sample given above, it works, but with the real file, it does not.
The filename also contains it's path, because it's categorized, could it be problematic?

Comment: @DavidDosa Most probably Sample json in question isn't the simplified case of the real one. Put your json to http://json2csharp.com/ and see what it generates for you.

Comment: The page generates classes for every file in the Json, 3k classes, not the best, i think.
The problem seems like to be in the filenames. It contains the path to the file too. ("sounds/ambient/cave/cave4.ogg")

Comment: If you need performance, this solution is about 10% better and alocate a little less memory according to [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet)
```
// deserialize JSON directly from a file
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"c:\movie.json"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    Movie movie2 = (Movie)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(Movie));
}
```
fonte: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the C# conventions and do not expose member variables as public or start property names with lower case. In order to make your conventional objects deserializable, you could use the System.Runtime.Serialization DataContract and DataMember attributes. DataContract indicates that an object of this type is serializable and DataMember is used to specify a property's serialization name.

```
class ResFile
{
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    [DataMember(Name = "hash")]
    public string Hash { get; set; } 

    [DataMember(Name = "size")]
    public int Size { get; set; }

    public ResFile () { }
}

[DataContract]
class ResFileCollection
{
    [DataMember(Name ="files")]
    public Dictionary<string, ResFile> Files { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the deserialization:

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("data.json");
        var files = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResFileCollection>(json);
        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, ResFile> f in files.Files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", f.Key, f.Value.Name, f.Value.Hash);
        }
```

Serialized property names should also be shorter for better performance. An example:

```
[DataMember(Name="src")]
public string SourcePath { get; set; }
```

Comment: `you could use the System.Runtime.Serialization DataContract and DataMember attributes` No Json.Net doesn't require them. Following c# naming convention is good, but You don't need any extra *Attribute* even for this. Json.Net will handle it automatically.

Comment: It does not require them but it doesn't ignore them either. They also imply that the type is supposed to be serialized, making the code somewhat more readable. In some cases having long strings in JSON could be problematic. PascalCase is also not in Javascript's conventions.

Comment: Of-note anyone using this DataContract solution should check the MSDN article here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data .  It requires a few extra assemblies:  System.Runtime.Serialization.Primatives and System.Runtime.Serialization.Json , but is more in-line with Microsoft specifications than letting a third-party JSON library handle the runtime component.  Upvoted as this solution remains more in-line with C# .NET Microsoft specifications than the others.